# Count repeated characters in a string

Tags: r

How do find the length of highest repeated character in a string

```
col1                         repeated letter           repeated number
apples333                      2                                     3
summer13                       2                                     0
talk77                         0                                     2
Aa6668                         2                                     3
```

I can use `lengths(regmatches(str, gregexpr("a",str)` or `str_count(str,"a")` but the idea is to automatically check which is the highest repeating char/number and return count.

Comment: Vicky, welcome to Stackoverflow. You will find a lot of helping friends here, if you post a reproducible example of your problem and show what you have done or where you struggle with getting the output that you desire.     Next to the example - as a minimum put the result of `head(your_df)` or `dput()` here.     2nd next: Canu you elaborate on the "highest" repeated character?  Looking at `apple` , are you looking for 2 * p := 2? I cannot make sense from the `apples333 2 3 summer ....`

Comment: Hi Ray, really appreciate your response & advice. What I am trying to extract is the number of highest repeated characters. So in apple333 , in terms of letters only p is repeated so that would be 2 & another column for only highest repeated numbers would be 3. However if the string is  - Appllles44777 then for letters column it  should be 3 (i.e. for l's) and for numbers it should be 3 (i.e. for 7s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *rle* and *rawConversion* functions:

```
d <- data.frame(col1 = c("apples333", "summer13", "talk77", "Aa6668"))

foo <- function(x, p){
  r <- rle(charToRaw(tolower(x)))
  res <- max(r$lengths[ grepl(p, rawToChar(r$values, multiple = TRUE)) ])
  if(res == 1) res <- 0
  res
  }  

d$repLetter <- sapply(d$col1, foo, p = "[a-z]")
d$repNumber <- sapply(d$col1, foo, p = "[0-9]")

d
#        col1 repLetter repNumber
# 1 apples333         2         3
# 2  summer13         2         0
# 3    talk77         0         2
# 4    Aa6668         2         3
```

Comment: Thank you, what I did was d$repletter <- lapply(gregexpr("11+", d$col1), function(x) length(x[x > 0])) & made 9 columns, lol which I am sure isnt effective at all :).  Will try your method and see how it looks. once again TY !

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an elegant `regex`-based solution for this (obviously I am not a big regex-er). The following is based on determining the `run length of a vector` using the base-`rle()` function, i.e. counting the repetition of elements.

As a strategy, we develop a function to work on a single string input providing the different portions and associated occurrences/counts. Then, to operate over several input strings, we apply (loop) a function to each element of the input vector.

**single loop**

Let's see how `rle()` works:

```
x <- "abba"    # a test string - who does not know ABBA

x_split <- strsplit(x, "") %>% unlist   # split the string, unlist to coerce vector
x_rle   <- rle(x_split)                 # apply rle()

# now let's check what we have
x_rle
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:3] 1 2 1
  values : chr [1:3] "a" "b" "a"
```

`rle()` returns a list. As you want to filter, etc. on your results, it might be easier to turn this into a data frame. We also store the actual input.

With a view to apply this to other strings (e.g. loop over input vector), we wrap this into a function call:

```
library(dplyr)

check_rle_char_num <- function(x){
# split the string and count occurrences
   x_split <- strsplit(x, "") %>% unlist()
   x_rle   <- rle(x_split).

# turn it into a tibble
   df      <- with(x_rle, tibble(values, lengths)) %>% 

# ----------- store the input string and check for chars/numerics
       mutate(   input = x
              , is_num = grepl(pattern = "[0-9]", values)   # logical check for numbers
       ) %>%
# ----------- order output tibble
       select(input, everything())
}
```

check that it works:

```
> (    check_rle_char_num("Appllles44777")    )
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  input         values lengths is_num
  <chr>         <chr>    <int> <lgl> 
1 Appllles44777 A            1 FALSE 
2 Appllles44777 p            2 FALSE 
3 Appllles44777 l            3 FALSE 
4 Appllles44777 e            1 FALSE 
5 Appllles44777 s            1 FALSE 
6 Appllles44777 4            2 TRUE  
7 Appllles44777 7            3 TRUE
```

We have all the pieces on which you can filter, select, etc. your desired output.

**loop over multiple input strings**

We use `tidyverse's` `{purrr}` package for this.

```
# multiple input strings
my_strings <- c("apples333", "summer13","talk77","Aa6668","Appllles44777")

# loop over my_strings
library(purrr)

test <- my_strings %>% 
   map_dfr(.f = ~ check_rle_char_num(.x))    # map_dfr returns a data frame

test
# A tibble: 29 x 4
   input     values lengths is_num
   <chr>     <chr>    <int> <lgl> 
 1 apples333 a            1 FALSE 
 2 apples333 p            2 FALSE 
 3 apples333 l            1 FALSE 
 4 apples333 e            1 FALSE 
 5 apples333 s            1 FALSE 
 6 apples333 3            3 TRUE  
 7 summer13  s            1 FALSE 
 8 summer13  u            1 FALSE 
 9 summer13  m            2 FALSE 
10 summer13  e            1 FALSE
```

**final push, filter, and reshape a nice output tibble**

```
# per problem statement - filter for maximum and min 2 counts (i.e. > 1)
result <- test %>% 
   group_by(input, is_num) %>% 
   filter(lengths == max(lengths), lengths > 1)

> result
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   input, is_num [7]
  input         values lengths is_num
  <chr>         <chr>    <int> <lgl> 
1 apples333     p            2 FALSE 
2 apples333     3            3 TRUE  
3 summer13      m            2 FALSE 
4 talk77        7            2 TRUE  
5 Aa6668        6            3 TRUE  
6 Appllles44777 l            3 FALSE 
7 Appllles44777 7            3 TRUE
```

Emulating a bit your results listed in the problem statement, one can reshuffle the columns and provide "nice" column names:

```
library(tidyr)   # for reshuffling

result %>% 
   tidyr::pivot_wider( names_from  = is_num
                     , values_from = c(values, lengths)
   ) %>% 

#---------- we spread the tibble, "spread" column-names combine previous colnames and TRUE/FALSE - mind that TRUE were numbers
     rename(  char = values_FALSE
            , char_count = lengths_FALSE
            , nums = values_TRUE
            , nums_count = lengths_TRUE) %>% 

#---------- changing order of columns for nice output
     select(input, starts_with("char"), starts_with("num"))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   input [5]
  input         char  char_count nums  nums_count
  <chr>         <chr>      <int> <chr>      <int>
1 apples333     p              2 3              3
2 summer13      m              2 NA            NA
3 talk77        NA            NA 7              2
4 Aa6668        NA            NA 6              3
5 Appllles44777 l              3 7              3
```

**final notes**

The solution presented

- does the filtering on the result data frame (after the loop). If there are no other operations on your data, you can lift this into the function.
- does not clean the NAs in the final output. If you need zeros for `no letter` or `no number`, you can replace the NAs.
- keeps characters and numbers in a single data frame. Obviously, you can split them. One could combine both again based on a `join()` or  `bind_cols()` on the input-variable. This saves the pivot-wider bit.
- does not care for "ties", i.e. you have a sequence of multiple characters and/or numbers with the same count. You may have to handle this.

Last but not least: simplify the code, if none of the columns/variables kept in the tibble help for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You can go with this:

```r
library(stringr)

max_freq <- Vectorize(function(x) max(tabulate(factor(x))))
df$repeated_letter <- max_freq(str_extract_all(str_to_lower(df$col1), "[:alpha:]"))
df$repeated_letter <- max_freq(str_extract_all(str_to_lower(df$col1), "[:digit:]"))

df
#>            col1 repeated_letter repeated_number
#> 1     apples333               2               3
#> 2      summer13               2               1
#> 3        talk77               1               2
#> 4        Aa6668               2               3
#> 5 Appllles44777               3               3
```

**Explanation**

Following a breakdown of the solution step by step with some explanations:

```r
# take your column
df$col1 |>
  
  # set to lower so A and a is the same character
  str_to_lower() |> 
  
  # extract only letters or digits as list of vectors
  str_extract_all("[:alpha:]") |> 
  
  # get frequency table for each vector
  lapply(factor) |> lapply(tabulate) |>
  
  # extract the count of most repeated letter for each table and return a vector
  sapply(max)
#> [1] 2 2 1 2 3
```

**Data**

Where `df` is:

```r
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("apples333", "summer13", "talk77", "Aa6668", "Appllles44777"))
```

**Warnings**

When there are no repeated characters, 1 will be returned, which is actually a more consistent answer, since the most repeated character will be repeated once. If you prefer zero, you can replace all ones with zeros.

In case of no characters or no numbers, `-Inf` will be returned. If you want a different result (like zero) you can replace it. In your example, it was not specified an occurrence like that.

Answer (score 0):

Though late to the party but this method might still be of interest:

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
d %>%
  # count the number of character repetitions:
  mutate(
    # for letters:
    dup_w = lapply(str_extract_all(col1, "(?i)([a-z])\\1+"), nchar),
    # for numbers:
    dup_n = lapply(str_extract_all(col1, "([0-9])\\1+"), nchar)) %>%
  # throw all repetition counts into a single column:
  pivot_longer(c(dup_w, dup_n)) %>%
  # show items in list:
  unnest(cols = value) %>%
  # group:
  group_by(col1, name) %>%
  # reduce dataframe to maximum values per group:
  filter(value == max(value)) %>%
  # widen the dataframe back to original format:
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   col1 [5]
  col1            dup_w dup_n
  <chr>           <int> <int>
1 11applesssss333     5     3
2 summer13            2    NA
3 talk77             NA     2
4 Aa6668              2     3
5 Appllles44777       3     3
```

Data (with lots ore repetitions to make things clearer):

```
d <- data.frame(col1 = c("11applesssss333", "summer13", "talk77",
                         "Aa6668", "Appllles44777"))
```